# Plot the characteristics for Burgers equation in Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, graphing-functions, matlab, hyperbolic-equations

I'm trying to plot the characteristics for the following problem.

> Consider the first order nonlinear hyperbolic PDE (the inviscid Burgers' equation)
> $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0 , \tag{1.2a} $$
> with the boundary and initial conditions defined by
> $$ u(0,t) = 0,\qquad u(x,0) = \begin{cases}
> \sin^2(\pi x) &\quad 0\leq x\leq1,\\
> 0 &\quad 1\leq x\leq 2.
> \end{cases} \tag{1.2b}
> $$

So far I have managed to find all the gradients for the lines from each value of $x_0$. But I'm not sure how to plot it. It seems like a very simple question but one I'm finding really difficult. I also cannot use any inbuilt matlab functions except the very minimal ones such as plot.

Here is my code so far..

```
dx=0.01;%spatial step
dt=dx;%set time and space steps equal
X=2;%end of space interval
x=0:dx:X;%space vector formed
Tf=1;%end of time interval
n=floor(X/dx);%number of overall space steps
n1=floor(1/dx);%number of space steps needed - 1st interval
timesteps=floor(Tf/dt);%number of time steps

u1=sin(pi*x).*sin(pi*x);
u11=u1(1:n1);
u2=zeros(1,n1+1);

%initial conditions

u0=[u11,u2]; %form ic vector u0
u=u0;
c=1./u0;%gives the gradients of each x0 point
```

Answer (score 1):

In the present case, the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) leads to the characteristic curves
$$
x = x_0 + \phi(x_0) t , \qquad 0\leq x_0\leq 2 ,
$$
where $\phi = u(\cdot,0)$ is the initial data. Along these curves, we have $u = \phi(x_0)$. Let us plot those curves for several values of $x_0$:

```
phi = @(x) (x<1).*sin(pi*x).^2;
[xmin,xmax,tmax,n] = deal(0, 2, 1.2, 30);
x0 = linspace(xmin,xmax,n);
x = linspace(xmin,xmax,200);
for i = 1:n
  plot(x, (x-x0(i))/(phi(x0(i))+eps), 'k-');
  hold on
end
ylim([0,tmax]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('t');
```

Output:

[image: characteristic curves]

See also the Maple version in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354787/418542).